# Help thinking about sample space probability

Tags: probability

I'm trying to come to grips with the more formal definition of random variables but am misunderstanding something

So the sample space is $Ω = \{ω_1, ω_2, \dots,  ω_n\}$ is finite just for simplicity.

and events A,B are subsets of this

I don't properly understand how to represent the event which is the intersection of $A$ and $B$ as a subset of the sample space? examples or advice would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: If $A = \{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$ and $B = \{\omega_1,\omega_3\}$ then $A \cap B = \{\omega_3\} \subset \Omega$, for example.

Comment: Why is it ω3 and not ω1?

Comment: I'm sure Frank meant $\{\omega_1\}$.  But his example is pretty much it.  Given two subsets $A\subset\Omega$, $B\subset\Omega$, then $A\cap B \subset \Omega$ (because it is a subset of $A$ and $B$), and the elements of $A\cap B$ are just those which appear in both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, $\{\omega_1\}$!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roll a 6 sided dice once and you get one of six outcomes $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, your sample space.
Let A be the event "A number greater than 2 is rolled" which is the subset A = {3, 4, 5, 6} of $\Omega$.
Let B be the event "A number less than 5 is rolled" which is the subset B = {1, 2, 3, 4} of $\Omega$.

The event "A and B" are those outcomes from S which are in *both* A and B i.e. the intersection of the two subsets. Then

"A and B" = {3, 4}

Note that events A and B are not independent of each other. P(A) = P(B) = 4/6 while P("A and B") = 2/6 so that P("A and B") is not P(A)P(B).
To create events A and B which are independent we typically need to perform two or more experiments which do not influence each other e.g. Toss a coin and roll a dice. The outcomes of this combined "single" experiment are the 12 pairs 
$\Omega$ = {(H, 1), (H, 2), ..., (T, 5), (T, 6)}
Now we can define two events from $\Omega$

A = A head is tossed = {(H, 1), ..., (H, 6)}

B = A 6 is rolled = {(H, 6),(T, 6)}

Then "A and B" = A head is tossed and a six is rolled = {(H, 6}), the common outcome in A and B.

Intuitively, A and B should be independent of each other. In this case, P(A) = 6/12 = 1/2, P(B) = 2/12 = 1/6 and P("A and B") = 1/12 which has the same value as P(A)P(B).

Answer (score 1):

It's just the intersection $A\cap B$. Often the sample space is not a simple as you have shown, even for simple experiments. For example, think about tossing a coin. For a single toss, the sample space is $$\mathscr S_1 = \{H,T\}.$$ But for multiple tosses, say two, the sample space becomes
$$ \mathscr S_2 = \mathscr S_1 \times \mathscr S_1 =\{ (H,H),(H,T),(T,H),(T,T)\}$$

If $A$ is the event "same result on both tosses", then
$$A=\{(H,H),(T,T)\}$$
while if $B$ is the event "at least one head on any toss", then
$$B=\{(H,H),(H,T),(T,H)\}.$$
This means the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is "head on both tosses", and indeed
$$A\cap B = \{(H,H)\}.$$
To make matters more complicated, it doesn't have to be a single repeated experiment, *e.g.*, you could be tossing a coin and spinning a spinner that can select a number from 1 to 9.